# How do I add a javascript file out of app.js in Lineman , in the beginning of the HTML?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, single-page-application, bower, linemanjs

I'm using Lineman and I have to include Modernizr.js before the body tag in my page. The regular app.js should be in its default location, at the end of the body. It happens that every javascript file I include in the project gets bundled inside app.js .

Answer (score 0):

I just fugure out how to deal with this problem. I just use the "static" folder under the Lineman project. Every asset you put there gets untouched. So I created a "js" folder and put my modernizr.js file ther. In the web page, just need to reference it by "js/modernizr.js".

I'm just loving Lineman.js. Really cool!